# grab the ip the application is running on

Tags: c++, visual-c++, networking, network-programming

i have a server application running. now what i'm looking to do is i need to specify the ip address of this server that is running the application, so in this case if the servers ip address was set as something like `111.111.111.111` how could i grab that `111.111.111.111` ip address inside that application in a windows system and once thats done display the servers ip in it's integer form?

i'm not looking to display its local ip, that being something like `127.0.0.1` or even `192.168.x.x`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get that info reliably without making a connection to an external server and checking the request IP (which could still be wrong if the request is going through an opaque proxy).

The reason for this is that Windows doesn't actually (necessarily) know the world-visible IP address, as it could be many, many network hops away. So the solution would be to write a simple script that would spit out the incoming request's IP address when requested, then make an HTTP request to that URL to determine the public IP.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the IP address which the server has to the outside, I recommend:

`lynx --dump http://www.whatismyip.com | grep 'Your IP Address Is'`

and then you can grab the IP using RegEx. Of course, this needs `lynx` to be installed. If you need to do it within the application, you need to specify which language the application is programmed in and how exactly it is working.

Comment: http://checkip.dyndns.org/ may be easier, but WhatIsMyIP also offers a (kind of) API.  See their [Automation page](http://www.whatismyip.com/faq/automation.asp)